# Getting employee from different tables depending on invoice type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables something like this:

```
**Invoices:**
InvoiceId Type Number EmployeeId
1          A   100    -1
2          B   200    11
3          A   300    -1
4          B   400    13


**Deliveries:**
DeliveryId InvoiceId EmployeeId
1          1         10
2          2         500
3          2         501
4          3         12
5          4         502
6          4         503
```

Invoice is connected to 1 or many deliveries.
Employee is a person who signs the delivery or invoice.

The logic in my data is:
If there is only one delivery joined to invoice we read employee from Deliveries, this is Type A.  If there are more deliveries we read employee from Invoices, this is Type B

I would like to get:

```
InvoiceId Number TrueEmployee
1         100    10
2         200    11
3         300    12
4         400    13
```

or eventually

```
InvoiceId Number InvoiceEmployee DeliveryEmployee
1         100    whatever        10
2         200    11              whatever
3         300    whatever        12
4         400    13              whatever
```

I tried

```
Select InvoiceId,Number,Invoices.EmployeeId,Deliveries.EmployeeId
from Invoices inner join Deliveries
on Invoices.InvoiceId=Deliveries.InvoiceId
```

but it will return multiple rows for each invoice if there are more than 1 delivery connected to it

Any ideas?
I'm using Ms SQL Server if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version without grouping, but with a more selective `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceId,
       i.Number,
       CASE i.Type WHEN 'A' THEN 999 ELSE i.EmployeeId END iEmployeeId, 
       COALESCE(d.EmployeeId,999) dEmployeeId 
FROM invoices i
LEFT JOIN deliveries d ON i.Type='A' 
                      AND d.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b8738/4

Just pick, whatever suits you best. 
(In my sample I used `999` as the value for 'whatever'.)

Comment: Thanks! This really works for me - JOIN to Deliveries only if the invoice type is appropriate. No more double rows.